# Staggered recycler view layout, imageview with default background color

Tags: android

I want staggered layout like pinterest app.

When I fix imageview height default background color it appears but when it is wrap in default color it does not appear

Help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: Your question is too broad, without any example you've done. Please read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

If you are using staggered recycler view then your height should not be fix, if you set fix height then then you won't experience staggered effect in recycler view. To resolve your issue you should set image to image view via `src` property instead of using color.

Comment: Sir. I set the src @color/brown, still its not working until do not fix height its not working.

Comment: It will not work with color you have to set image for that like placeholder images like this: https://www.google.com/search?q=placeholder+image&safe=active&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN8J-ui-rdAhXFO48KHdTwCLUQ_AUIDigB&biw=1313&bih=675#imgrc=8Ht_vXdcFcjsUM:

Comment: Yes, but i want the effect like in pininterest app, placeholder doest contains any image but fill with different random color.

Comment: You are going in wrong way, this not how things work, problem is if you set color, 
but color has no height, no width then how can view show you that color, wrap content won't work because content(color) has no width, height so it's not showing you color.

Comment: If you wan't to show color, then you have to give fix height but in that case staggered won't work best thing is to use placeholder.